# Nginx Rewrite Rule (working partially)

Tags: redirect, nginx

In Nginx, I want to redirect

```
http:/domain.com/subscribe
```

to

```
http:/domain.com/#/subscribe.
```

At the same time, `http://domain.com/subscribe/something` should not get redirected.

I used the rule

> if ( $request_filename ~ subscribe) { rewrite ^
>   http:/domain.com/#/subscribe permanent; }

But the problem with this rule is, it redirects whatever that comes after subscribe to `http://domain.com/#/subscribe`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
location = /subscribe {
  return 301 $scheme://$http_host/#$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
    rewrite ^/(subscribe|faq)$ http://domain.com/#/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/(subscribe|faq)/$ http://domain.com/#/$1 permanent;
```